# Set html figure-width to same as width of image it contains

Tags: html, css, image

When having a image inside a figure-tag, the figure width is 100%. How do I make so that the the figure always will have the same width as the image? Here's my current code:

HTML:

```
<figure>
    <img src="http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png" alt="" />
</figure>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

figure {
    border: 1px solid red;
}

img {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add `display:table` to `figure` css like this

```
figure 
{
    display:table;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

[JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XLQuF/)

Comment: display: inline-block; would be better

Comment: @RomainPellerin ya thanks for your suggestion but could you plz explain the benefit of using `inline-block` here ? thanks.

Comment: because of the likely default display properties applied by each browser

Answer (score 2):

Event though you have not asked for any JS solution .here is my solution for your problem.

On image load change width and height of figure

Assuming figure is parent of img

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
         $("img").load(function(){

              $(this).parent().width( $(this).width());

           });   
    });
```

Comment: This is actually my favorite answer. There isn't an easy pure-css solution for this particular case. http://codepen.io/gpspake/pen/WbpBop

Answer (score 0):

You could also do this with jquery, even though it's a bit of a hack:

```
var imgWidth = $("figure img").width();
     $("figure").width(imgWidth);
```

This is a fix if, for some reason, display: table isn't working for you in your css stack, or you need that element to be a different display type.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the CSS that solved this issue for me:

```
figure{
display: table-cell;
}
```

A plain CSS solution that I discovered while looking for a solution to the same problem raised. I really didn't want a JavaScript approach and this did it for me.
Note: I encountered the problem in a custom theme I'm developing on WordPress.

Comment: But why did it solve the issue, please edit your answer and explain

Comment: @RohitGupta, It's just a plain CSS solution that I discovered while looking for a solution to the same problem raised. I really didn't want a JavaScript approach and this did it for me. Note: I encountered the problem in a custom theme I'm developing on WordPress.

Comment: You misunderstand. I  don't need the explanation.  If you merge the comments with your answer, it makes it s whole lot better.  Otherwise it may get removed by the community bot.