# Display image caption on the bottom of the image

Tags: html, css, figure

I'm trying to display an image caption at the bottom of an image.

[image]

That is what I have at present. The caption is supposed to be at the bottom of the image and match its width. The reason that it is not doing so is because the `<figure>` that contains the image is not resizing to match the image.

```
<figure class="fig">
    <img src="http://such.url" class="fig__media"/>

    <figcaption class="image-caption-text">Some caption</figcaption>
</figure>
```

I did some searching and found that typically you need to add `display: inline-block`, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15557769/set-html-figure-width-to-same-as-width-of-image-it-contains). That has no effect here. My suspicion is that this is because the image itself has CSS with `position: absolute`. If I remove that bit the layout breaks. (Not my CSS and I'm not a web dev.) So it seems like I need a way to get the `<figure>` to resize even though the image uses absolute position. Or some other way to correctly position the caption.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i would suggest to do it like that `position: absolute;` for the `figcaption` not the `img` that the `figure` can take the **width** of the `img`

```css
figure {
  border: 1px solid;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
}

figcaption {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 1em;
  left: 0;
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<figure class="fig">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/500x200" class="fig__media"/>

    <figcaption class="image-caption-text">Some caption</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Comment: That worked. For those curious, here is the change I made: https://github.com/wmde/website/commit/fd2851a33dd52fe1f392c084d59702bb5902a864